# failed to recognize concept type as bool in SFINAE

Tags: c++, c++20, sfinae, c++-concepts

consider this example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

template<typename T>
concept Printable = requires(const T a) {
    a.print();
};
template<typename T>
constexpr auto is_printable() {
    return Printable<T>;
}

template<class T, std::enable_if_t<is_printable<T>()>* = nullptr>
constexpr void do_print(T data) {
    data.print();
}

struct foo {
    void print() const {
        std::cout << "Hello World\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    foo f;
    do_print(f);
}
```

trying to compile this on MSVC (Version 16.9.4, /std:c++latest) will produce these errors:

```
Error   C2783   'void do_print(T)': could not deduce template argument for '__formal'
Error   C2672   'do_print': no matching overloaded function found
```

It failed to satisfy the `std::enable_if_t`.

---

I discovered the error comes from the `auto` in `constexpr auto is_printable() { ... }`, and replacing the the `auto` with `bool` will correctly compile.

```
template<typename T>
constexpr bool is_printable() {
    return Printable<T>;
}
```

I find this very bizarre, the concept `Printable<T>` is evaluated at compile time and should produce a `constexpr bool`. Why does `auto` fail suddenly?

Comment: Unrelated to the issue: why are you using `enable_if` with a function that returns the value of a concept, rather than just `template <class T> requires Printable<T>` or `template <Printable T>`?

Comment: there is a large section of code that is slowly replacing all C++17 SFINAE's with concepts, it's surely a mess right now because it uses both. And this exact scenario happened producing the weird error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an MSVC bug. Your code is correct. I highly recommend reporting the issue. [Your code works correctly on GCC and Clang](https://godbolt.org/z/M74WrPEbj).

---

In the meantime, I would simply drop the SFINAE. It is not really needed when you got concepts that replaces enable ifs:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

template<typename T>
concept Printable = requires(const T a) {
    a.print();
};

constexpr void do_print(Printable auto data) {
    data.print();
}

struct foo {
    void print() const {
        std::cout << "Hello World\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    foo f;
    do_print(f);
}
```

You can also use `requires` or even replace `typename` with your concept:

```
template<typename T> requires Printable<T>
constexpr void do_print(T data) {
    data.print();
}

template<Printable T>
constexpr void do_print(T data) {
    data.print();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I filed a bug report [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/failed-to-recognize-concept-type-as-bool/1402410)